# How to execute a command and put the answer in a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to take nam (the inputted username) and put it in a dictionary with the encrypted form of the password. I have a dictionary which has defines all letters with random characters called encrypt. I am hoping it to add "username" : "encrypted form of the inputted password",

```
def create():
    nam=raw_input("Username - ").lower()
    if nam in listy:
        print "Sorry, that username is already taken."
        nam=raw_input("Username - ").lower()
    passw=raw_input("Password - ").lower()

    listy[nam] = for i in list(passw):
        encrypt[i]
    print "You have successfully made an account! You may login now."
    login()
```

Comment: Define the `encrypted form of the inputted password` please

Comment: @GLHF Sorry for not getting to you sooner. I have a dictionary called encrypt. It defines all letters with random string. ex:(a:7r289r2iurb##@!,b:@#$#@53566gdfasdasd...)   I want to take the inputted password and get the "encrypted" form of it. I want to take all the letters in the password then get the definition of it. ex:(Inputted password is "ab" I want it to take the letters and input it to the dictionary, where it is turned into the random string of characters that defines the letter. In this case, (7r289r2iurb##@!@#$#@53566gdfasdasd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure what you mean, but I will take a guess

```
listy[nam] = ''.join([encrypt[i] for i in passw])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in an infinite `while` loop. Encrypting it is depends on your imagination actually. I just reverse the password in the example.

```
mydict = {}

while True:
    nam = raw_input("Username: ").lower()
    if nam in mydict:
        print ("Sorry, that username is already taken.")
        continue
    passw = raw_input("Password: ").lower()
    mydict[nam] = passw[::-1]
    print ("You have successfully made an account! You may login now.")
```

In this example, if the password is `hello`, it'll going to dict in reverse format `olleh`. You can define another dict like `a:*df!,b:-UOl`.. then convert the password to a complicated string. Whenever you ask the password to user to login, reverse the string again. Like;

```
if mydict[nam] == passw[::-1]:
    print ("Passsword is correct.")
```

So you keep the password in your dict in reverse format, but when the user enter his password, you checking that reversing it again.

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I use your method, it has an error. In this case, Bob is the username. When I open the code in IDLE, it looks like it was not added to the dictionary. (Note: I changed some of the variable's names)                                                        "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonPrograms\ACCOUNT_LOGIN.py", line 52, in <module>
    login()
  File "C:\PythonPrograms\ACCOUNT_LOGIN.py", line 36, in login
    if listy[user] == password[::-1]:
KeyError: 'bob'"